# Why does casperjs (phantomjs engine - Ubuntu x86_64 16.04) crash at the commandline?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

```
root@krusty:/www/site.com# casperjs ./amazon_login.js
Title: Amazon Sign In
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@krusty:/www/site.com#
```

I can't figure out why. Anyone here know about this? I don't know what else to type but this is saying I have to add more text bulk to the code snippets I'm displaying so here's what I've done: I've searched Google for the text of this crash and found out that I had to export a certain QT variable, so I did that as well, it progresses the script function just a little when executing phantomjs but still crashes.

If I run it exclusively from 'phantomjs' and uncomment the first few lines of the script code written below I get this output:

```
root@krusty:/www/nuper.com# /root/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs ./amazon_login.js
Title: Amazon Sign In
Capping
Done
FAIL TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'casper.done()')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'casper.done()')
#           phantomjs://code/amazon_login.js:54:16
#           checkStep@phantomjs://platform/casper.js:423:28
#    stack: not provided
PASS Untitled suite in null
```

Code in amazon_login.js that is accessed by phantomjs:

```
//phantom.casperPath = '/root/node_modules/casperjs';
//phantom.injectJs('/root/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');

// if you need the test environment then you need this
//phantom.casperTest = true;

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0');
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

var AMAZON_USER = '<removed>';
var AMAZON_PASS = '<removed>';

casper.start('https://www.amazon.com/').thenClick('a#nav-link-accountList', 
function() {
this.echo('Title: ' + this.getTitle());

var emailInput = 'input#ap_email';
var passInput  = 'input#ap_password';

this.mouseEvent('click', emailInput, '15%', '48%');
this.sendKeys('input#ap_email', AMAZON_USER);

    this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.mouseEvent('click', passInput, '12%', '67%');
        this.sendKeys('input#ap_password', AMAZON_PASS);

        this.mouseEvent('click', 'input#signInSubmit', '50%', '50%');
    });
});

casper.then(function(e) {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo('Capping');
        this.capture('amazon.png');
    });
});

/* casper.thenOpen('https://www.amazon.com/ss/help/contact/?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&ref_=v_sp_contact_seller&sellerID=A39LA0PG14JNN7',
        function() {
        this.echo('Second Page: ' + this.getTitle());
        this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.mouseEvent('click', 'span#a-autoid-7', '12%', '67%');
        this.mouseEvent('click', 'a#preOrderSubject_0', '12%', '67%');
        this.mouseEvent('click', 'input#a-button-input', '50%', '50%');
        this.echo('Title: ' + this.getTitle());

    });
});
*/
casper.run(function() {
    console.log('Done');

    casper.done();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps someone can help you if you provide your code? :)

Comment: Ok updated a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have `.done` method in your last line and you are invoking it on Casper object instead of test object. Done method is method of Tester module in Casper and you are calling your casper without Tester module.

As per while your code breaks in the 1st case I suggest you to listen for all the error events like `page.error`, `resource.error`...

Hope that helps!